# How to post multipart content type in single request body using spring and restful service

Tags: spring, rest, web-services, restful-url

We have a requirement to post a multiformats request type to send to a resful api..I am a beginer and need help with a sample program hiw to post multiple requests with different format like json and pdf in single http request so that I can get a response back?can anyone please post a sample code how to implement multi part content type?

Answer (score 0):

I've had already developed an upload microservice using multipart/form-data requests. The example bellow is a simple endpoint that accepts multiple files using multipart/form-data. You only need to use the spring MultipartFile class as the argument.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity upload(
         @RequestPart(value = "files") MultipartFile[] files) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

For more details I highly recommend reading the spring official guide in uploading files: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Comment: But I need to know how to create a request which will have multipartcontent with contnet type and boundary in the request